# re-execution of a python program

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I'm writing a python program using spyder which calls a function from another python program.

When I execute my program for the first time, I have the results as expected and everything is good.
But, when I try to execute it another time it shows this error message:

> local variable 'D_fluid_mn' referenced before assignment

The variable `D_fluid_mn` is defined in the function I am calling in this program and it's inside a loop in this function.

But when I restart spyder, the program works but just for the first time and after that, I have the same error message every time.

How can I fix this?

Comment: put in the code that you tried..

Comment: its too big!!!!